# Bootstrap-Date picker date field not saving to mysql db

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've small form which has date field, where I'm trying to save  into the database.All other fields are getting saved except the date field from datepicker.Below is the view and controller

```
def addreminder
@user = set_user  

@userremind=UserReminder.new do |u|
  u.user_id=params[:id]
  u.car_id=params[:car]
  u.reminder=Time.local(params[:reminder_date]).strftime('%Y/%d/%m')
  u.service_type=params[:service_type]
  u.active_status=0
end
```

Show view

```
   <%= form_tag("/users/addreminder/#{current_user.id}",:method=>"post",:id => 'add_reminder') do %>
     <%= select_tag(:car, options_for_select(@cars.collect{|u|[u['car_name'],u['id']]}),
       {class: "span3 input-md main_select"}) %>
      <%= label :service_type,"Select Service Type"%> 
      <%= select_tag(:service_type, options_for_select(@services.collect{|u|[u['service_type'],u['service_type']]}),
       {class: "span3 input-md main_select"}) %>     
 <%= (text_field_tag :reminder_date,nil,placeholder: "Select Reminder Date",data: {provide: "datepicker"})%>       
       <%= submit_tag "Remind me",:class=>"btn btn-xlarge"%>
                        <% end %>
       <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
  }); 
 </script>
```

Here is the log params

```
    Parameters:          {"utf8"=>"✓""authenticity_token"=>"7wSEVk24GAgpMtIYoEsa195DYsqB4UsOQ6BoAMzgOfc=", "car"=>"27", "service_type"=>"Oil Change", "reminder_date"=>"07/02/2015", "commit"=>"Remind me", "id"=>"5"}
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5   ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `user_reminders` (`active_status`, `car_id`, `created_at`, `service_type`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["active_status", 0], ["car_id", 27], ["created_at", Fri, 26 Jun 2015 19:52:10 UTC +00:00], ["service_type", "Oil Change"], ["updated_at", Fri, 26 Jun 2015 19:52:10 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 5]]
(32.8ms)  COMMIT
```

The database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user_reminders ( 
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  car_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  service_type varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  reminder varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
  active_status int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
  updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The model:

```
class UserReminder < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user 
  attr_accessor :reminder 
  validates :reminder, presence: true 
  # validate :reminder_date_cannot_be_in_the_past 

  def reminder_date_cannot_be_in_the_past 
    errors.add(:reminder, "Can't be in the past") if reminder_date <= Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Does your 'user_reminders' table have a `reminder` column?

Comment: Did you add `reminder_date` to the list of permitted arguments in your controller?

Comment: @WallyAltman, yes it has column called reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this does not work:

*First:* The `attr_accessor :reminder` line overrides the setter and getter that Rails already provides for the `reminder` column. As a result you are unable to set values on the "real" `reminder`. Delete the `attr_accessor :reminder` line from your model.

*Second:* `Time.local` cannot parse the string from the params.

```
Time.local('07/02/2015').strftime('%Y/%d/%m')
#=> "0007/01/01"
```

Use `Time.parse` instead:

```
Time.parse('07/02/2015').strftime('%Y/%d/%m')
#=> "2015/07/02"
```

*Third:* Your custom validator tries compares two different things. `reminder_date` does not exist and `Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` has another format than the one saved in the text column. Change that method to:

```
def reminder_date_cannot_be_in_the_past 
  if reminder <= Date.today.strftime('%Y/%d/%m')
    errors.add(:reminder, "can't be in the past")  
  end 
end
```

Furthermore there are a few things to consider:

IMO it makes sense to change the type of the `reminder` column to `DATE`. That would make the code much easier, because you could then compare `Date` objects and you would need the `strftime` method calls.

And it seems to me like you do not handle validation errors. Might make sense to handle the result of the `save` call and return the errors to the user if it fails.

Comment: Still same issue here is the updated controller,data does not recorddef addreminder
    @user = set_user  
 
    @userremind=UserReminder.new do |u|
      u.user_id=params[:id]
      u.car_id=params[:car]
      u.reminder=Time.parse(params[:reminder_date]).strftime('%Y/%d/%m')
      u.service_type=params[:service_type]
      u.active_status=0
    end

Comment: I really do not need, just trying different options,let me try above

Comment: Nope it does not work, the weird thing is even if I hard code the value, data does not enter.But all other values are getting inserted

Comment: class UserReminder < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
  
        attr_accessor :reminder
      validates :reminder, presence: true
  #validate :reminder_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
     def  reminder_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
      errors.add(:reminder, "Can't be in the past") if
       reminder_date <= Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
     end 
  
  
end

Comment: CREATE TABLE `user_reminders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminder` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I had to strip down everything b'coz the value was not being saved. If you look at my code I commented reminder_date_cannot_be_in_the_past  validation also my field in the database was date, just changed it to check if string can be saved anyways.But non of those work

Comment: @user501307: I updated my answer again, because I found the actual bug when I reformated your model's code in your question. See the new *First*.

Comment: Finally, like you pointed it was att_accessor blocking the data .It saving to the database.But funny part is , its only letting me select date from  07/01 and failing with "out of range" error.Anyways thanks alot for helping out